# How to convert images taken in a fish eye camera into plane (rectangular) images using opencv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, fisheye

Is there any predefined code for this or I have to write my own code?
Also, I do not have the camera properties for this, I have only the image taken in fisheye lens and now I have to flatten the images

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV provides a module for working with fisheye images: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html

[This](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0) is a tutorial with an example application.

Keep in mind that your task might be a bit hard to achieve since the problem is under-determined. If you have some cues in the image (such as straight lines), that might help. Otherwise, you should seek a way of getting more information about the lens. If it's a known lens type, you might find calibration info online. Also, some images might have the lens used to capture them in the EXIF data.